# weakly defective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Could anyone give us some references on weakly defective varieties?
Could anyone explain some good methods to show one variety is not weakly defective?
Thank you!

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should register on MO and then someone can merge all of your different accounts. Otherwise, each of your accounts will have small rep and thus prevent you from leaving comments, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can read for instance the following article:

L. Chiantini - C. Ciliberto: "Weakly defective varieties", Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 354 (2001), p. 151 - 178,

which contains, among other results, the classification of weakly defective irreducible surfaces. This paper also gives a good list of references.

If you are looking for some techniques to prove weak non-defectivity, try reading

E. Ballico: "On the weak non-defectivity of Veronese embeddings of projective spaces", Central European Journal of Mathematics 3 (2005), p. 183-187.